# What is ~that~ on the floor?

Tags: grammar

Consider these three questions:

> 1) What is that?
>
> 2) What is that on the floor? (You point your finger to the floor.)
>
> 3) ***What is ____ on the floor?*** (Didn't point to the floor, just know that there is something on the floor and you asked it while doing your own thing.)

In the third situation, what word should be you? Using "that" also?

Comment: You seem to assume such uses of ***that*** (and ***this***) require *pointing* at the referent. They don't - it's sufficient that the context makes it clear *something* is being referenced, even if it's not currently visible, and the addressee has never seen it. For example (conversation between two people *inside* the house): *"What's that on the doorstep?"*  *"I don't know - I haven't been outside this morning"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd find any of these grammatical and not unnatural:

> What is **that** on the floor?
>   What is **that thing** on the floor?
>   What is **this thing** on the floor?
>   What is **this** on the floor?
>   **What is on the floor**?
>   **What the heck** is on the floor?

Which one I'd utter might depend on a number of factors:

- I might be more likely to use *that* when the object is further away, and *this* when I'm very close to it.
- I may be more likely to add the word *thing* if the object is rather bulky (rather than, say, a small stain)
- I might be more likely to use the last one if I'm agitated (e.g., if I've just stubbed my toe in the dark)

Comment: Would it be okay to say "What is *there* on the floor?"

Comment: I'd say 'yes' but I'd be looking for the pointing finger again.

Comment: I will choose "What is on the floor?".

Comment: @CopperKettle: I'd ask *What's that on the floor there?*

Comment: @TRomano: thanks! Would that obviate the need for finger-pointing?

Comment: Usually the question would be punctuated with a very slight nod of the head, the speaker looking in the general direction of the thing. Pointing is optional. :-)

Comment: A related question: *What's that doing on the floor?*  E.g. it should be on the table or on the shelf. Did someone leave it on the floor? Has it fallen off the shelf?  I.e. Why is it on the floor?

Answer (score 1):

"What is that on the floor"
Perfectly acceptable, so long as the answer is not going to be "3 odd shoes, a sleeping dog on a rug, my old scarf, 6 bottles, a broken TV & last week's Times crossword"

That is, assuming the answer has a choice of only one item, otherwise you'd have to point with words instead of your finger…
"What is that woollen thing on the floor?"
"My old scarf"